# I am looking to determine the difference between 2 "HH:mm:ss.fff" values in VB

Tags: .net, vb.net, parsing, datetime, timespan

I am struggling to get the exact value between two cells in a datagridview.  Both values are in HH:mm:ss.fff format but when i try to calc the difference i can't show the .fff in the textbox.  I know that i need to format in some way but every way i try provides errors.  My code is below.  I do not want to show date or year in anyway and the data in the cells will always come in with HH:mm:ss.fff.

Thanks in advance.  Using Visual Studio 2013

```
    Dim value2 As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(dgvConvert(3, 1).Value)
    'value is in "HH:mm:ss.fff" format i.e 08:01:05.900
    Dim value1 As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(dgvConvert(3, 2).Value)
    'value is in "HH:mm:ss.fff" format i.e 08:01:50.000

    Dim timespan2 As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(value2)
    Dim timespan1 As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(value1)

    Dim duration As TimeSpan = timespan1 - timespan2

    Dim duration1 As String = duration.ToString

    txtResult.Text = duration1.ToString
    'result is "00:00:05" but i am trying to get "00:00:05.900"
    'txtResult.Text = duration(format("HH:mm:ss.fff")) does not work.
```

Here is the code that i use to write the CSV to the DataGridView

```
    Private Sub btnLoadFileToConvert_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLoadFileToConvert.Click
    ' MessageBox.Show("Make sure your file only contains numbers in the first coumn", "Check File")
    dgvConvert.Rows.Clear()
    Dim TextLine As String = ""
    Dim SplitLine() As String
    Dim fname As String = txtFileToConvert.Text
    If System.IO.File.Exists(fname) = True Then
        Dim objReader1 As New System.IO.StreamReader(fname)
        Do While objReader1.Peek() <> -1
            TextLine = objReader1.ReadLine()
            SplitLine = Split(TextLine, ",")
            Me.dgvConvert.Rows.Add(SplitLine)
        Loop
        objReader1.Close()
        objReader1.Dispose()
    Else
        MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")

    End If
    dgvConvert.RowCount = 6001
```

Comment: Why do you parse twice ?`

Comment: If it is a DateTime value stored there. why do you parse at all?

Comment: Put Option Strict On at the top of the source code file to help the compiler help you.

Comment: LUC, I parse twice bc that is how I wrote it but that does not mean that it is the best code.  I am a beginner for sure.  Plutonix, it appears that i need to parse it to get it into a text box.  i was unable ot simply perform the calc without parsing.  Hans-I do not know what that means :)

Comment: What is the data type of the actual values in the cells?  Are they `String` objects?  `Date` objects?  `TimeSpan` objects?  Something else?

Comment: They are actually strings (i had to recheck and apologize for the miss information).  I added the code that writes the CSV that contains names and times into the datagridview to my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your cells always contain a time value, you can parse them into a [TimeSpan structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx). Then you can subtract one from the other.

If you want to display the value showing milliseconds you can use the [overload of .ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632(v=vs.110).aspx) which accepts a format (note this is slightly different to the DateTime format as some chars need to be escaped.

```
    'values for debug
    Dim cell2Value = "08:01:05.900" 'dgvConvert(3, 1).Value.ToString
    Dim cell1Value = "08:01:50.000" 'dgvConvert(3, 2).Value.ToString

    Dim value2 = TimeSpan.Parse(cell2Value)
    Dim value1 = TimeSpan.Parse(cell1Value)

    TextBox1.Text = (value1 - value2).ToString("hh\:mm\:ss\.fff")
```

Comment: Matt.  Thank you and your comment made me recheck.  I apologize but i am bringing the data in as a string from a csv save file that contains names and times(times are in the  "HH:mm:ss.000") excel format.  Here is the code that i use to read the csv to the dgvConvert.

Comment: Works like a champ!  Thank you so much!